# How can I post on a friend's Facebook wall with Android

Tags: android, facebook

I make an application in which I make an EditText and a button. I want to be post that message which is written on EditText on the Facebook friends wall after clicked on the button. Please give me some idea how we can perform this task using Facebook sdk.

The code is below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.post_wall);

        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        friend_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wall_to);
        wall = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wall);

        savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
        savedInstanceState.getString("to");

        onComplete(savedInstanceState);

    }

@Override public void onComplete(Bundle values)
    {

        Utility.currentPermissions.clear();


        if (values.isEmpty())
        {
            //"skip" clicked ?
            return;
        }

        // if facebookClient.authorize(...) was successful, this runs
        // this also runs after successful post
        // after posting, "to"(which is the id of friend) is added to the values bundle
        // I use that to differentiate between a call from
        // faceBook.authorize(...) and a call from a successful post
        // is there a better way of doing this?
        if (!values.containsKey("to"))
        {
            try
            {
                Log.d("Wall try", "Click successfully");

                for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
                    if (parameters.getByteArray(key) != null) {
                        parameters.putByteArray(key, parameters.getByteArray(key));

                        Log.d("key", parameters.getByteArray(key).toString());
                    }
                }

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        performActivityInfo();
                    }
                });


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }



protected void performActivityInfo() {

        Log.d("perform wall", "Perform Activity");
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FRIEND_WALL);


        parameters.putString("message", wall.getText().toString());
        facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);// "stream.publish" is an API call
        Log.d("Wall post", "Click successfully");

    }

    public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case FRIEND_WALL:
                Log.d("Handler WALL", "Handler");
                postOnWall(wall.getText().toString());
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };



 @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            facebookClient = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            // replace APP_API_ID with your own
            Log.d("Wall click", "Click successfully");
            facebookClient.authorize(this,
                new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);
    }

    public void postOnWall(String msg) {
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
         try {
                String response = facebookClient.request("me");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", msg);
                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                response = facebookClient.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                        "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If u got any problem in this code then please provide me some sample code. I have need this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the value from Edit Text just use :

EditText edittext;

```
edittext.getEditableText().toString();
```

Inside Button click Listener use this code then

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String entered_value=edittext.getEditableText().toString();
            try{
                parameters.putString("message", entered_value);
                parameters.putString("target_id", "XXXXX"); // target Id in which you need to Post 
                parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
                String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
                Log.v("response", response);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    });
```

where button is your button Object.